# Appending NSString with Zeros depending upon length

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `string`, length may vary but I have to check if its length is less then 12 and if yes append those many zeros to it.

Like:

- `str = Test123`, output should be `Test12300000`
- `str = Test123456`, output should be `Test12345600`

Only 12 Char is allowed in string.

Tried below code but not getting generic result. There must be a better and easy way to do.

```
- (NSString *)formatValue:(NSString *)str forDigits:(NSString *)zeros {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", str ,zeros]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
- (NSString *)stringToFormat:(NSString *)str {
    while (str.length <12) {
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0", str];
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i tested with 10 digit and it gave me 12 digit with two zeros at the end ...i will test for rest different string. thank you once again.

Comment: You are welcome! :) @user2813740

Answer (score 1):

This is fast and simple, I think.

```
- (NSString *)stringToFormat:(NSString *)str {
    return [str stringByAppendingString:[@"000000000000" substringFromIndex:str.length]];
}
```

Just make sure the string is never more than 12 characters.

Comment: Thank you. i tested and it work fine for 10 digit.